# How can i split a string into tokens by '&'

Tags: c, split, strtok

I´m tying to split a string into tokens by ';'. But I have a problem that some tokens are empty/null, for example; 123;123132;;;232;232323;;;;1;
So i can´t use strtok becasuse merges adjacents delimiters. I see that you post this solution:

```
include <string.h>

char *data = "this&&that&other";
char *next;
char *curr = data;
while ((next = strchr(curr, '&')) != NULL) {
    /* process curr to next-1 */
    curr = next + 1;
}
/* process the remaining string (the last token) */
```

But I don´t understand because when I do next-1 to get the firts value i only get the firts word of the value not all the whole value. 
Can you help me?, do you have any idea how to split this?
I´m programmig in C ansi. I see in another post that exists a strsep function thats seems exactly what i need, but in C ansi library this functions is not included.
Thanks and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is want you want :-

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* mystrsep(char** input, const char* delim)
{
  char* result = *input;
  char* p;

  p = (result != NULL) ? strpbrk(result, delim) : NULL;

  if (p == NULL)
    *input = NULL;
  else
  {
    *p = '\0';
    *input = p + 1;
  }

  return result;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "123;123132;;;232;232323;;;;1;";
  const char delimiters[] = ";";
  char* ptr;
  char* token;

    ptr = str;
  token = mystrsep(&ptr, delimiters);
  while(token)
    {
      printf("%s\n",token);
       token = mystrsep(&ptr, delimiters);
    }   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strtok_r_noskip(char *str, const char *delims, char **store){
    char *p, *wk;
    if(str != NULL){
        *store = str;
    }
    if(*store == NULL) return NULL;
    //*store += strspn(*store, delims);//skip delimiter
    if(**store == '\0') return NULL;
    p=strpbrk(wk=*store, delims);
    if(p != NULL){
        *p='\0';
        *store = p + 1;
    } else {
        *store = NULL;
    }
    return wk;
}


int main(void){
    char data1[] = "this&&that&other";
    char *store, *token = strtok_r_noskip(data1, "&", &store);
    for(; token ; token = strtok_r_noskip(NULL, "&", &store)) {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", token);
    }
/* output
"this"
""
"that"
"other"
*/
    char data2[] = "123;123132;;;232;232323;;;;1;";
    token = strtok_r_noskip(data2, ";", &store);
    for(; token ; token = strtok_r_noskip(NULL, ";", &store)) {
        printf("\"%s\"\n", token);
    }
/* output
"123"
"123132"
""
""
"232"
"232323"
""
""
""
"1"
*/

   return 0;
}
```